# Material-ui DatePicker - how to change color of day of the week letters and arrows

Tags: colors, datepicker, material-ui, styling

I'm trying to change the colors of days of the week letters ( S M T W T F S ) as well as arrows that change months on DatePicker modal. I was able to change modal background and year dropdown by applying this as a theme override:

```
MuiPaper: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      backgroundColor: "#eaea87",
      color: "white",
    },
  },
},
```

[days of the week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFq3l.png)

Unfortunately I can't find a way to change days of the week letters nor left/right arrows that change months. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you clarify in what way you are trying to change the day of the week letters? Are you just trying to change the font style and/or color? Or do you want to display them in a different order? Or use a different language? Also for the arrows, are you trying to replace the arrows with a different icon, or just change the icon color?

Comment: I've updated the description - for both days of the week letters and arrow icons I only need to change the colors.

Answer (score 0):

To change the arrows you need to change the color of svg component:

```
svg:{color:"white"},
```

To change the color of the week days you need to change the span component:

```
span:{color:"white"},
```

Both of these are properties of the paper, so inline change would look like this:

```
 PaperProps={{
            sx: { svg:{color:"white"}, span:{color:"white"},
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the colors of the day of week letters, you can try with this:

```
<DatePicker
    label="Date*"
    value={value}
    dayOfWeekFormatter={(_day: string) => _day}
    onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
    slotProps={{
      layout: {
        sx: {
          '& .MuiDayCalendar-weekDayLabel': {
            color: 'red',
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
          },
        },
      },
    }}
  />
```

[datepicker preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZXhL.png)